# Adding an App does not shown up to users in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We have SharePoint 2013 farm, and a developed created a webpart which was added to the App Catalog. I have a full permission to all site collections via user policy and the developer has a site collection administrator (SCA). For some reason, I am the only one who can search and see the app when I go to the site collection and other users do not. 
I have checked the settings for the App in the app catalog as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just added "all users" active directory group to the app catalog site collection with "Read" permission and now users are able to view and add App uploaded to the App Catalog site.